# Question on Rudin 10.5

Tags: integration, matrices, analysis, inverse, jacobian

[image]

[image]

I don't understand what does it mean that "A primitive mapping is thus one that changes at most once coordinate" ( what do we mean in darkened $x$ in the $10.5$ ? is it the set of all points $x$ $\in$ $E$ where $g(x)$ $\neq$ $0$ ? )

Hence, I don't understand from where does  the $(10)$ inequality come.
$G(x) = x + [g(x) - x_m]e_m$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\mathbf x$ stands for a vector in $\Bbb R^n$. Suppose, say, that $n=4$ and that $m=3$. Then$$G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\bigl(x_1,x_2,g(x_3),x_4\bigr).$$So, only the third coordinate of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ is changed. And then$$G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)+\bigl(0,0,g(x_3)-x_3,0\bigr).$$

Comment: $$G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\bigl(x_1,x_2,g(x_3),x_4\bigr).$$ can you explain this line more explicitly?

Comment: Rudin is saying that there is a function $g\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$\bigl(\forall(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\Bbb R^4\bigr):G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\bigl(x_1,x_2,g(x_3),x_4\bigr).$$So, $G$ leaves the first, second and fourth coordinates unchanged and only changes (eventually) the third coordinate.

Comment: What has your second comment to do with your question?

Comment: it's part of $10.5$

Comment: I know. But it is **not** part of your question.

Comment: I know but I forgot it to ask in the question. so I would be grateful if you will answer on this question too

Comment: For instance (taking again my previous assumption that $n=4$ and that $m=4$), the second component of $G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ is just $x_2$. The partial derivative of this with respect to $x_1$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ is $0$, whereas its partial derivative of this with respect to $x_2$ is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You should understand that i$\neq m $ doesn't mean that i $\lt m $